# PHP: Getting current full url and href to each word in a variable

Tags: php, html

```
<?php

    $test = 'Ontario, Montreal, Quebec';

?>
```

How do I href each word like this with current full url of the page from single variable but multiple words to href each seperately.

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/canada">Ontario</a> <a href="http://www.domain.com/canada"> Montreal</a> <a href="http://www.domain.com/canada"> Quebec</a>
```

[Ontario](http://www.domain.com/ontario)  [Montreal](http://www.domain.com/montreal)  [Quebec](http://www.domain.com/quebec)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a simple application of [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), which splits a string into multiple substrings based on a delimiter, in this case ", ".

```
$test = "Ontario, Montreal, Quebec";
$words = explode(", ", $test);
foreach ($words as $word) {
    echo "<a href='http://www.domain.com/" . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] . "'>$word</a>";
}
```

Comment: @Mas You want *every* link to go to the same URL, but have different text? I'll update my answer.

Comment: @Mas You mean the URL of the page the user is currently on? This seems rather contrived, but I'll add it.

Comment: yep url of the current page user is on at very moment.

Comment: @Mas Test that out, it should be what you want.

Comment: it seems to work partially, I'm getting this url http://www.domain.com/canada</a><a href=

Comment: It's giving extra </a><a href= along the link, how to remove it

Answer (score 1):

Taken from **@jli** with slight modification.

```
<?php
$test = "Ontario, Montreal, Quebec";
$words = explode(",", $test);
array_walk($words,"trim");

foreach ($words as $word) {
    echo "<a href='http://www.domain.com/{$word}'>$word</a>";
}
?>
```